# Why is my case statement not returning the value in my "else" clause?

Tags: sql, string, case, sql-null

I have this section of code and my ELSE is not working. It should return 'UNKNOWN' but I am still seeing NULLs in my results. What is going on?

```
      case 
            when t2.NEURO_GRP_2 is not NULL then t2.NEURO_GRP_1 --ASSIGN GROUP 2 BASED ON PRIMARY DX CODE
            when t2.NEURO_GRP_2 is null AND t6.NEURO_GRP_2 IS NOT NULL then t6.NEURO_GRP_2 --ASSIGN GROUP 2 BASED ON CLINIC
            when t2.NEURO_GRP_2 is null AND t6.NEURO_GRP_2 IS NULL then t3.NEURO_GRP_3 --ASSIGN GROUP 2 BASED ON PROCEDURE GROUP
            ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
            end AS NEURO_GRP_2,
```

Comment: Maybe `when t2.NEURO_GRP_2 is not NULL then t2.NEURO_GRP_1` should be `when t2.NEURO_GRP_2 is not NULL then t2.NEURO_GRP_2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(t2.NEURO_GRP_2, t6.NEURO_GRP_2, t3.NEURO_GRP_3, 'UNKNOWN')
```

This returns the first non-`NULL` value.  As formulated with a constant as the last argument, it can never return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like `coalesce()` does what you intend:

```
coalesce(t2.NEURO_GRP_2, t6.NEURO_GRP_2, t3.NEURO_GRP_3, 'UNKNOWN') S NEURO_GRP_2
```

The problem with your original code *probably* is that:

- there is a mismatch in the first condition (you check the nullity of one column, but return another one)
- the conditions are somehow redondant, and not properly cascaded

You might have been meaning:

```
case 
    when t2.NEURO_GRP_2 IS NOT NULL then t2.NEURO_GRP_2
    when t6.NEURO_GRP_2 IS NOT NULL then t6.NEURO_GRP_2
    when t3.NEURO_GRP_3 IS NOT NULL then t3.NEURO_GRP_3
    else 'UNKNOWN' 
end AS NEURO_GRP_2
```

... Which is exactly what `coalesce()` does.